# Acrobat pdf custom field validation not allowing valid input

Tags: validation, pdf

Working on a form in Acrobat DC, and I need to restrict entry in one field (`addtl_tables`) if a previous field (`first_table`) is empty. In other words, I want the form to disallow entries and further calculations on the `addtl_tables` field if the `first_table` field has not been filled out yet.

Here is the code I'm using for validation on the `addtl_tables` field:

```
if (this.getField('first_table') != 1) {
event.value = '';
}
```

When I test this, the `addtl_tables` field never accepts any entry at all, even when `first_table` contains valid data.

This should be pretty simple, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your script.

First...

```
this.getField('first_table')
```

...only gets the field Object, not it's value. Use...

```
var fieldValue = this.getField('first_table').value
```

...to get the value of a field using its name.

Second, field validation scripts look at the value of the event.rc property to determine if the entered value is valid or not. You need to set this value in your code; true means valid.

However, to achieve the goal you describe, the validation script is not where you want to run your code, the validation script runs against a committed value. You want to prevent input. Add some code to the custom format event in the keyboard script of "addtl_tables" to prevent input when 'first_table' is empty. Something like...

```
if (this.getField('first_table').value == '') {
    event.change = '';
}
```

... should work.